# retrieve list of country name in both English and Swedish

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

How can I retrieve a list of all country names in both english and swedish. like this list https://www.iban.com/country-codes but I also need the swedish country name.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a suitable question for stack overflow. If you're looking for a list of country names in Swedish then you need to search online for that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how this really is a C# coding problem!

But you can get a list of them in various languages here:
https://stefangabos.github.io/world_countries/

You will however probably have to combine this yourself if you want it in multiple languages.

Comment: I dont see how this is a c# problem either, it was just a question on how to solve an issue I had. Thanks for the link

Comment: If you find it useful, then please don't forget to upvote!